# what are tagged structures and how are they different from ordinary structures?

Tags: c

i don't understand why second structure has 2 labels person and person_create. how is the second structure return a pointer .

```
struct Person{
    char *name;
    int age;
    int height;
    int weight;
};
struct Person *Person_create(char *name,int age,int height,int weight){
    struct Person *who = malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
    assert(who != null);

    who->name = strdup(name);
    who->age = age;
    who->height = height;
    who->weight = weight;
    return who;
};
```

Comment: `Person_create()` is a function returning a pointer of type `struct Person`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct Person *Person_create(char *name,int age,int height,int weight)
```

Read this line

```
Person_create
```

is a function name and this function returns a pointer to a structure which is

```
struct Person *
```

Comment: thanks a lot. i feel dumb for not recognizing that its a function

Answer (score 1):

There's no second structure. It's a function returning `struct Person` and its name is `Person_create`.